# Determing if Android APK was created using Corona Labs SDK

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to determine or have a clue if an Android App APK was created leveraging the Corona Cross Platform SDK from CoronaLabs? Will the android manifest have any activities or values that might indicate it came from Corona?  Will any files exist such as specific Lua files that give an indication?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are any files in the apk that indicate it's a Coronalabs package. But you can determine it in runtime by checking the Android logfile when running the application. Try it using adb with the following syntax:

```
adb logcat Corona:v *:s
```

Good luck!